# Hide view item of NSStackView with animation

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsstackview

I working with swift 4 for macOS and I would like to hide an stack view item with animation.

I tried this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var stack: NSStackView!
    var x = 0



    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        if x == 0 {

            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({context in
                context.duration = 0.25
                context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true

                self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.isHidden = true
                self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
                x = 1
            }, completionHandler: nil)

        } else {

            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({context in
                context.duration = 0.25
                context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true

                self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.isHidden = false
                self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
                x = 0
            }, completionHandler: nil)

        }

    }
}
```

The result will be:

[image]

It works!
But I am not happy with the animation style.
My wish is:

- I press the button, the red view will be smaller to the right side
- I press the button, the red view will be larger to the left side.

Like a sidebar or if you have an splitview controller and you will do `splitviewItem.animator().isCollapsed = true`

this animation of show/hide is perfect.
Is this wish possible?

**UPDATE**
`self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.animator().frame = NSZeroRect`

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

`self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.animator().frame = NSRect(x: self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.frame.origin.x, y: self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.frame.size.height)`

[image]

Comment: Instead of animating "isHidden", animate "frame" of red view where you can set width = 0

Comment: I tried this: `self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.frame.size.width = 0.0` but than it happens nothing, when i press the button

Comment: No no... It is cocoa, not cocoa touch. You should use something like: yourView.animator().frame = NSZeroRect

Comment: `self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.animator().frame = NSZeroRect`result in my first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just create a simple testing code which can animate the red view, instead of using button, I just used touchup, please have a look at the code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

let view1 = NSView()
let view2 = NSView()
let view3 = NSView()
var x = 0

var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view1.wantsLayer = true
    view2.wantsLayer = true
    view3.wantsLayer = true

    view1.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.orange.cgColor
    view2.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    view3.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor

    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(view1)
    self.view.addSubview(view2)
    self.view.addSubview(view3)

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[view1]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view1": view1]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[view2]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view2": view2]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[view3]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view3": view3]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[view1(==view2)][view2(==view1)][view3]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view1": view1, "view2": view2, "view3": view3]))

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view3, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
    self.view.addConstraint(constraint)
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    if x == 0 {

        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({context in
            context.duration = 0.25
            context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true

            constraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
            x = 1
        }, completionHandler: nil)

    } else {

        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({context in
            context.duration = 0.25
            context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true

            constraint.constant = 100
            self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
            x = 0
        }, completionHandler: nil)

    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: thx that you help me. i modify the code like this: `self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.animator().frame = NSRect(x: self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.frame.origin.x, y: self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: self.stack.arrangedSubviews.last!.frame.size.height)` the animation looks good, but the view will come back :/ result in my first post

Comment: sry I understand the code, but I dont understand, why the view will always come back

Comment: @Ghost108 please check my latest update. If you used auto layout, then you should animate constraint.constant for red view's width.

Comment: thy, now it works if I change the width of the constraint, too :)

Comment: This is a good technique, but the question is actually about NSStackView specifically. And, you cannot use this technique with a stack view unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Organize Your User Interface with a Stack View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/views_and_controls/organize_your_user_interface_with_a_stack_view) sample code.

I disliked the *heightContraint* on the view controller and the height calculation in the *-viewDidLoad*. The code below calculation the size before animating and only adds the contrain while animating.

#### Breakable Contraint

First you need to set the priority of the contraint to something lower than 1000 *(required constraint)* for the direction you want the animation. Here the bottom contraint.

While we animate the view **in** and **out**, we will add contraint to do so **with** a priority of 1000 *(required constraint)*.

[image]
[image]

#### Code

```
@interface NSStackView (LOAnimation)
- (void)lo_toggleArrangedSubview:(NSView *)view;
@end

@implementation NSStackView (LOAnimation)
- (void)lo_toggleArrangedSubview:(NSView *)view
{
    NSAssert([self detachesHiddenViews], @"toggleArrangedSubview requires detachesHiddenViews YES");
    NSAssert([[self arrangedSubviews] containsObject:view], @"view not an arrangedSubview");
    CGFloat postAnimationHeight = 0;
    NSLayoutConstraint *animationContraint = nil;
    if (view.hidden) {
        view.hidden = NO; // NSStackView will re-add view to its subviews
        [self layoutSubtreeIfNeeded]; // calucalte view size
        postAnimationHeight = view.bounds.size.height;
        animationContraint = [view.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0];
        animationContraint.active = YES;
    } else {
        [self layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];  // calucalte view size
        animationContraint = [view.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:view.bounds.size.height];
        animationContraint.active = YES;
    }
    [self layoutSubtreeIfNeeded]; // layout with animationContraint in place
    [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
        context.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        animationContraint.animator.constant = postAnimationHeight;
        [self layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
    } completionHandler:^{
        view.animator.hidden = (postAnimationHeight == 0);
        [view removeConstraint:animationContraint];
    }];
}
@end
```